# How can we use two separate redis DB client in single nodejs app

Tags: node.js, redis

I want to have more than one Redis client object as multiple DB instance like DB0 (O INDEX REDIS DB).
Currently, I'm using

```
let RedisClient = require("./redis");
RedisClient.select(1, function (err, res) {
  // any operation here
});
```

so `RedisClient` is having DB1 instance. what is the best way to deal with multiple db if we want to use another DB2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `redis.createClient()` twice

```
const redis = require("redis");
const client_1 = redis.createClient(REDIS_1_HOST, REDIS_PORT_1);
const client_2 = redis.createClient(REDIS_2_HOST, REDIS_PORT_2);
```

see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#rediscreateclient

Comment: Thanks for answering. So basically connecting within multiple DB among the given 16 DBS, we must create multiple clients by passing option to db value.